# Is there a method preventing dynamic ec2 key pairs from being written to tfstate file?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp-vault

We are starting to use Terraform to build our aws ec2 infrastructure but would like to do this as securely as possible.

Ideally we would like to do is to create a key pair for each Windows ec2 instance dynamically and store the private key in Vault. This is possible, but I cannot think a way of implementing it without having the private key written to the tfstate file. Yes I know I can store the tfstate file in an encrypted s3 bucket but this does not seem like an optimal secure solution.

I am happy to write custom code if needs be to have the key pair generated via another mechanism and the name passed as a variable to Terraform but dont want to if there are other more robust and tested methods out there. I was hoping we could use Vault to do this but on researching it does not look possible.

Has anyone got any experience of doing something similar? Failing that, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The most secure option is to have an arbitrary keypair you destroy the private key for and user_data that joins the instances to a [AWS Managed Microsoft AD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ms_ad_getting_started.html#create_managed_ad) domain controller. After that you can use conventional AD users, and groups to control access to the instances (but [not group policy in any depth](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2018/02/14/group-policy-settings-in-aws-directory-service.aspx), regrettably). You'll need a domain member server to administrate AD at that level of detail.

If you *really* need to be able to use local admin on these Windows EC2 instances, then you'll need to create the keypair for decrypting the password once manually and then share it securely through a secret or password manager with other admins using something like Vault or 1Password.

I don't see any security advantage to creating a keypair per instance, just considerable added complexity. If you're concerned about exposure, change the administrator passwords after obtaining them and store those in your secret or password manager.

I still advise going with AD if you are using Windows. Windows with AD enables world-leading unified endpoint management and Microsoft has held the lead on that for a very long time.

Comment: Totally get that AD is the way to go and will be the case when we move to production but for now I need to be able use local users and admin.

From your answer, it seems that this is not possible. In which case I think I will go down the route of using 1 key pair for all and changing the password during the configuration step of the automation.

Comment: In fairness, it is possible to keep the private key out of the state file and still automate this, but only if you use ssh-keygen with a null_resource local-exec provisioner, but it's awkward and not very repeatable. Given that you'll stull have to distribute the SSH private key to other operators, you're probably better off creating a single key manually unless you can automate uploading the key to your secret manager.